How to align x-axis ticks to starting in Stacked Column chart when using React-ApexCharts?
Tick should be from starting not middle of the Stacked Column chart.
I also tried with range and tickAmount param but that is not affecting that much.
On x-axis if we select bar chart then it's breaking UI ticks.
Current Output :

Expected Output (as you can see ticks are middle align this should be like this):


Problem :

x-axis tick should be from starting not middle of the bar chart

Cause :

When tickPlacement 1 is 'on' then x-axis ticks are at center of the bar (like first image), when 'between' then ticks are like 2nd & 3rd image.

Solution :
In options, under x-axis key pass :
tickPlacement: 'between'
xaxis: {
  tickPlacement: 'between',
}

Also remove keys range and tickAmount, add them later if needed.
Live Snippet (in JS, options, hence no issues if used in ReactJS) :


var options = {
          series: [{
          name: 'PRODUCT A',
          data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43, 21, 49]
        }, {
          name: 'PRODUCT B',
          data: [13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27, 33, 12]
        }, {
          name: 'PRODUCT C',
          data: [11, 17, 15, 15, 21, 14, 15, 13]
        }],
          chart: {
          type: 'bar',
          height: 350,
          stacked: true,
          stackType: '100%'
        },
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom',
              offsetX: -10,
              offsetY: 0
            }
          }
        }],
        xaxis: {
          categories: ['2011 Q1', '2011 Q2', '2011 Q3', '2011 Q4', '2012 Q1', '2012 Q2',
            '2012 Q3', '2012 Q4'
          ],
          tickPlacement: 'between',
        },
        fill: {
          opacity: 1
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 50
        },
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
      
      
   
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id='chart'/>



Please Read :

tickPlacement : https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis (Click on key tickPlacement it will scroll down & show values)

